# Html game, getting image to move when a function is called

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm making a html 5 game and I'm trying to make the "monster" move on it's own. the "hero" moves just fine but the "monster" won't. The problem is probably in the update or render methods but I'm at a loss for what I'm missing.

```
    ////////////////////////////////////Canvases////////////////////////////////////

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = 988;
    canvas.height = 480;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    ////////////////////////////////////Map Fields//////////////////////////////////

    var mapCordsX = 0;
    var mapCordsY = 0;

    //to save the area code when the player is in a building
    var oldMapCordsX = 0;
    var oldMapCordsY = 0;

    //////////////////////////////////Images////////////////////////////////////////

    // Background image
    var bgReady = false;
    var bgImage1 = new Image();
    bgImage1.onload = function() {
        bgReady = true;
    };

    //images for backgorunds. 
    bgImage1.src = "images/background.png"; // Background images


    // Hero image
    var heroReady = false;
    var heroImage = new Image();
    heroImage.onload = function() {
        heroReady = true;
    };
    heroImage.src = "images/sprite01south.png";  //Hero Images


    // Enemyimage
    var monsterReady = false;
    var monsterImage = new Image();
    monsterImage.onload = function() {
        monsterReady = true;
    };
    monsterImage.src = "images/monster.png";     //Enemy images\

    //////////////////////////////////Images////////////////////////////////////////



    ////////////////////////////////Global Objects//////////////////////////////////

    // Game objects
    var hero = {
        speed: 256, // movement in pixels per second
        x: canvas.width / 2,
        y: canvas.height / 2

    };
    var monster = {
        speed: 256,
        x: canvas.width / 2,
        y: canvas.height / 2

    };
    var monstersCaught = 0;

    /////////////////////////// Handle keyboard controls////////////////////////////
    var keysDown = {};

    addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
    }, false);

    addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
        delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
    }, false);



    ///////////////////////////////Map Methods//////////////////////////////////////
    var resetNorth = function() {
        hero.y = 440;
        mapCordsY += 1;
    };
    var resetEast = function() {
        hero.x = 0;
        mapCordsX += 1;
    };
    var resetWest = function() {
        hero.x = canvas.width;
        mapCordsX += 1;
    };
    var resetSouth = function() {
        hero.y = 0;
        mapCordsY -= 1;
    };


    // resetCenter the game when the player catches a monster
    var resetCenter = function() {
        hero.x = canvas.width / 2;
        hero.y = canvas.height / 2;

        // Throw the monster somewhere on the screen randomly
        monster.x = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
        monster.y = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));
    };


    //////////////////////////////////Update Method/////////////////////////////////

   var update = function(modifier) {
    //key events
    if (38 in keysDown) { // Player holding up
        hero.y -= hero.speed * modifier;
        heroImage.src = "images/sprite01north.PNG";
    }
    if (40 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
        hero.y += hero.speed * modifier;
        heroImage.src = "images/sprite01south.PNG";
    }
    if (37 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
        hero.x -= hero.speed * modifier;
        heroImage.src = "images/sprite01west.PNG";
    }
    if (39 in keysDown) { // Player holding right
        hero.x += hero.speed * modifier;
        heroImage.src = "images/sprite01east.PNG";
    }



    var goblin1 = 0;

    if (goblin1 < 10){
      monster.x -= monster.speed * modifier;
    }
    else if (goblin1 <20 ){
      monster.x += monster.speed * modifier;
    }
    else if (goblin1 < 30){
      monster.y -= monster.speed * modifier;
    }
    else {
      monster.y += monster.speed * modifier;
    }

    goblin1++;

    if(goblin1 > 40){
      goblin1=0;
    }

        //Map change event triggers
        if (hero.y >= 440) {
            resetSouth();
        } else if (hero.y <= 0) {
            resetNorth();
        }
        if (hero.x <= 0) {
            resetWest();
        } else if (hero.x >= 988) {
            resetEast();
        }
        //map change events
        if (mapCordsX === -1 && mapCordsY === 0) {
            bgImage1.src = "images/background(-1,0).png";
        }
        //a lot more to come as I get backgrounds    
        // Are they touching?
        if (
            hero.x <= (monster.x + 32) && monster.x <= (hero.x + 32) && hero.y <= (monster.y + 32) && monster.y <= (hero.y + 32)) {
            ++monstersCaught;
            resetCenter();
        }
    };


    ////////////////////// Update game objects graphics/////////////////////////////



    // Draw everything
    var render = function() {
        if (bgReady) {
            ctx.drawImage(bgImage1, 0, 0);
        }

        if (heroReady) {
            ctx.drawImage(heroImage, hero.x, hero.y);
        }

        if (monsterReady) {
            ctx.drawImage(monsterImage, monster.x, monster.y);
        }
        // Score
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 250, 250)";
        ctx.font = "24px Helvetica";
        ctx.textAlign = "left";
        ctx.textBaseline = "top";
        ctx.fillText("Enemies Slayed : " + monstersCaught, 32, 32);
    };  
    //////////////////////////////////The main game loop////////////////////////////
    var main = function() {
        var now = Date.now();
        var delta = now - then;

        update(delta / 1000);
        render();

        then = now;

        // Request to do this again ASAP
        requestAnimationFrame(main);
    };

    // Cross-browser support for requestAnimationFrame
    var w = window;
    requestAnimationFrame = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || w.msRequestAnimationFrame || w.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

    // Let's play this game!
    var then = Date.now();
    resetCenter();
    main();
```

Comment: Do you mean hero moves , but monster doesn't ?

Comment: The image attached to hero will move when I press a arrow key but the monster image doesn't move on it's own after the update and render methods run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happen if you remove this if/else statement?

```
 //if (monsterReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(monsterImage, monster.x, monster.y);
//     }
```

Are you altering the var monsterReady in another part in your code?

Comment: didn't make a difference unfortunately

Comment: What are the x and y coordinates of monster variable when you call the update method. Can you add a debug line there? console.log( "x = "+monster.x +"," +"y =" + monster.y);

Comment: I can't get anything to print in the console at all.

Comment: Why not ? If you are using chrome press F12 and set a breakpoint at that line and inspect the values of the monster's coordinates. If that is not possible either, then replace that line for ctx.drawImage(monsterImage, 0,0);

Comment: It looks like it only changes when it resets after getting touched by the hero, not every time the update method it used.